# How to enable devexpress MVC upload control on client side

Tags: model-view-controller, devexpress

I have a problem when I try to enable MVC upload control. The upload control is initially disabled. I want the upload control to be enabled when the user select an option in CheckBoxList. UploadControl does not allow changing its enabled state on the client side but how to do that. Can you help me and give me some example how to do that with postback or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Place UploadControl inside a [CallbackPanel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9000).

```
@Html.DevExpress().CallbackPanel(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "CallbackPanel";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "CallbackPanelPartial" };
    // other settings
    settings.SetContent(() =>
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("UploadControlUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            Html.DevExpress().UploadControl(s =>
        {
            s.Name = "UploadControl";
            s.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "UploadControlUpload" };
            // other settings
            s.Enabled = (bool)ViewData["UPEnabled"];
        }).Render();
        }
    });
}).GetHtml()
```

We will store a variable that will indicate if the UploadControl is enabled in ViewData. So, I get its value on the CallbackPanel partial view. On our view, we will render the CallbackPanel in the following way:

```
@Html.Action("CallbackPanelPartial", new { CPEnabled = false })
```

And our controller method to process callbacks to the CallbackPanel is:

```
public ActionResult CallbackPanelPartial(bool CPEnabled) {
    ViewData["UPEnabled"] = CPEnabled;
    return PartialView("_CallbackPanelPartial");
}
```

When you check a CheckBox, send a callback to the CallbackPanel to enable the UploadControl. For this, handle [the CheckBox CheckedChanged client side event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientCheckBox_CheckedChangedtopic).

```
@Html.DevExpress().CheckBox(settings =>
{
    // other settings
    settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged = "function (s, e) { CallbackPanel.PerformCallback({CPEnabled: true}); }";
}).GetHtml()
```